# static variable is not changing. Yii, OOP

Tags: oop, static, yii

I have a code of index action of SiteController

```
  static $cid;

  public function actionIndex() {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        //return ajax data, includes this
                $data['redirectUrl'] = self::$cid;
       } 
       //code...
        self::$cid = 2;
        //code...
  }
```

The problem is $data['redirectUrl'] is always null. If announce variable like

```
static $cid = 2;
```

all works fine. Prompt me please, what is the problem, maybe i can't see obvious things?

Comment: Why you expect that `$cid` must contain some value? Where you assign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is as expected..

Do you expect the static variable to be stored in the session or something?

1) You are assigning a value to the variable AFTER you use it. When it's uninitialised you will always get back a NULL value.

2) The next time it is used is on the next request made to your action, which is a whole new process, thus the variable will again be empty.

I think the functionality you are looking for you will need to store the value in a session so it's kept for the next request :)

Comment: Thank you.
I just move down 'if' block, where i used variable and it's started to work =)